# Getting Bad request(404) when using DynamoDB with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB and I am getting `null (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 404; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)` error when using DynamoDB with spring boot. The server starts up pretty fine but breaks while making DB call. I have DynamoDB setup on local machine. My Gradle files looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa'
    implementation "org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.0.3.RELEASE"
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:1.4.6.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.github.derjust:spring-data-dynamodb:5.1.0'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: '1.11.348'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

I have tried this with **1.11.696** (latest) and with several other versions as well.

**Config file**

```
@Configuration
public class DynamoDBConfig {

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.endpoint}")
    private String amazonDynamoDBEndpoint;

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.region}")
    private String amazonDynamoDBSigningRegion;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
    private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
    private String amazonAWSSecretKey;

    @Value("${dynamodb.connection.timeout}")
    private Integer dynamoDBConnTimeout;

    @Value("${dynamodb.request.timeout}")
    private Integer dynamoDBRequestTimeout;

    @Value("${dynamodb.max.connections}")
    private Integer dynamoDBMaxConn;

    @Bean
    public AWSStaticCredentialsProvider awsStaticCredentialsProvider() {
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(
                amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey));
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientConfiguration dynamoDBConf() {
        return new ClientConfiguration()
                .withConnectionTimeout(dynamoDBConnTimeout)
                .withRequestTimeout(dynamoDBRequestTimeout)
                .withMaxConnections(dynamoDBMaxConn);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider awsStaticCredentialsProvider, ClientConfiguration dynamoDBConf) {
        AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder builder = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(awsStaticCredentialsProvider)
                .withClientConfiguration(dynamoDBConf);
        if ( StringUtils.isEmpty(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint) ) {
            builder.withRegion(dynamoDBRegions());
        } else {
            builder.withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint, dynamoDBRegions().getName()));
        }
       return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB){
        return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);
    }

    private Regions dynamoDBRegions() {
        try{
            return Regions.fromName(amazonDynamoDBSigningRegion);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
            return Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1;
        }
    }
```

**Service**

```
public class TemplateService {

    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;
    private AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB;

    @Autowired
    public TemplateService(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB, DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper){
        this.dynamoDBMapper = dynamoDBMapper;
        this.amazonDynamoDB = amazonDynamoDB;
    }

    public void init(){
        CreateTableRequest req = dynamoDBMapper.generateCreateTableRequest(Template.class);
        req.setProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(5L, 5L));
        amazonDynamoDB.createTable(req);
    }
    public void save(Template data){
        init();
        dynamoDBMapper.save(data);
    }

    public Template getById(String templateId){
        return dynamoDBMapper.load(Template.class,"1", templateId);
    }

}
```

**Entity Pojo**

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "template")
public class Template {

    String id;
    String templateId;
    String name;

    public Template() {
    }

    public Template(String id, String templateId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.templateId = templateId;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "template_id")
    @JsonProperty("template_id")
    public String getTemplateId() {
        return templateId;
    }

    public void setTemplateId(String templateId) {
        this.templateId = templateId;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Complete log**

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: null (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 404; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:5110) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:5077) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeGetItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2197) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.getItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2163) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:431) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:448) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.load(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:85) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.696.jar:na]
    at com.swiggy.owl.template.service.TemplateService.getById(TemplateService.java:35) ~[main/:na]
    at com.swiggy.owl.template.controller.TemplateController.get(TemplateController.java:23) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

I can see there are lots of links explaining similar error with 400 error code but nothing for this. I guess I making some mistake while calling the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after beating around the bushes, I found out that I was giving the db endpoint as http://localhost:8001 instead of http://localhost:8000. I was mistaken with the endpoint of a dynamodb-admin which was running on 8001.

Comment: I received a similar error, `AmazonEventBridgeException: null (Service: AmazonEventBridge; Status Code: 404; Error Code: null; ...`, and it was really hard to debug because of the **null** in the error message.
Now I know that it was because my endpoint configuration was wrong.
Thank you for posting this question!